# I run into trouble when i make my java Procedures to package,i do not know why?

Tags: java, builder, jhipster

[i use hipster to builder my procedures,but it is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOBsN.jpg)

i use hipster to builder my procedures ,but it tell me this Problem

Comment: I'm afraid this question is *very* unclear. You should provide both the code and the error message as *text*, along with much more description. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture you uploaded (please copy/paste the log here!), you have a missing column in your database, called `insurance_dead_line`.

So you probably didn't configure it your Liquibase changelog - did you create it with JHipster? Did you run `mvn liquibase:diff`? Or did you write your changelog manually?

You have many options: I don't know which one you chose (as you didn't write any explanation), but that's where you missed to configure that column.